# How to do a treatment-emergent data transformation in the S programming language?

Tags: r, statistics, sas

how would you do this in R?
( this is a data preparation task )
From the adverse events dataset, derive the treatment-emergent adverse
events dataset:
For each body system and preferred term, a row for each patient such
that either:

1. That adverse event occurred in the post-baseline period but not the baseline period, or
2. Even though the event did occur in the baseline period , it
   occurred post-baseline at a higher severity than observed during
   baseline

### Variables:

```
severity = 1 , 2 , 3 (integer code for mild moderate severe)
patid visit bodysys prefterm
Baseline rows are rows such that visit<=2
Post baseline rows are rows such that visit>2
```

Here is the data prep in SAS  , in 23 lines of code:

```
data base1_dset ;
 set ae_dset ;
 if visit<=2 ;

proc sort data=base1_dset ;
 by patid bodysys prefterm severity ;

data base2_dset ;
 set base1_dset ;
 by patid bodysys prefterm severity ;
 if last.prefterm ;

data post1_dset ;
 set ae_dset ;
 if visit> 2 ;

proc sort data=post1_dset ;
 by patid bodysys prefterm severity ;

data post2_dset ;
 set post1_dset ;
 by patid bodysys prefterm severity ;
 if last.prefterm ;
 rename severity = severity2 ;

data new_ae_dset ;
 merge base2_dset post2_dset ;
 by patid bodysys prefterm ;
 if severity2>severity or severity==. ;
```

And here is the data prep in Vilno Data Transformation , in 12 lines of code :
( for more see http://fivetimesfaster.blogspot.com )

```
inlist ae_dset ;
if not ( visit<=2 ) deleterow ;
select severity=max(severity) by patid bodysys prefterm ;
sendoff(base2_dset) patid bodysys prefterm severity ;

inlist ae_dset ;
if not ( visit>2 ) deleterow ;
select severity2=max(severity) by patid bodysys prefterm ;
sendoff(post2_dset) patid bodysys prefterm severity2 ;

inlist base2_dset post2_dset ;
mergeby patid bodysys prefterm ;
if not ( severity2>severity or severity is null ) deleterow ;
sendoff(new_ae_dset) patid bodysys prefterm severity2 ;
```

How would you do this in R?

thanks , Robert

PS the formatting of the code examples is horrendous, why is stackoverflow ignoring some of my return/newline characters?

Comment: about the formatting, see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: thanks, well it looks ok now, but the window underneath when i was typing looked different. looked at it and very helpful . Robert

Comment: I edited your post, that's why it looks ok now.

Comment: All that switching back and for between PROCs make my head hurt. Post an example dataset and I guarantee it can be done in one third of the number of lines.

Comment: to second DWin's comment - please post sample input data, the statistical tests / data manipulations you need performed, and the example data output. I for one don't speak a single line of SAS or Vilno Data Transformation code, but would be more than happy to provide a solution based in R if you can give us something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do more or less what you are asking (at least if the variables are numeric).  There will be better ways

```
smallvisit       <- ae_dset[ ae_dset$visit <= 2, ]
bigvisit         <- ae_dset[ ae_dset$visit >  2, ]
nams             <- c("patid", "bodysys", "prefterm")
smallvisitsorted <- smallvisit[ do.call( order, smallvisit[nams] ), ]
smallvisitsplit  <- split( smallvisitsorted, smallvisitsorted[nams], drop=TRUE )
last             <- function(a){ tail( a, 1 ) }
smallvisitlast   <- as.data.frame( t( sapply( smallvisitsplit, last ) ) )
mergedvisit      <- merge( bigvisit, smallvisitlast, by=nams, all.x=TRUE )
new_ae_dset      <- mergedvisit[ mergedvisit$severity.x > mergedvisit$severity.y | 
                                is.na( mergedvisit$severity.y ) , ]
```

For example if `ae_dset` looks like

```
   patid bodysys prefterm visit severity
1      5       9        2     1        3
2     22       1        5     5        2
3     11       2        9     3        3
4     11       2        9     2        2
5     22       3        3     3        1
6      3       4        6     1        2
7     22       3        3     2        2
8     22       3        3     4        3
9     11       2        9     1        1
10     3       3        6     5        2
11     4       3        7     7        3
```

then, using this code, `new_ae_dset` will look

```
  patid bodysys prefterm visit.x severity.x visit.y severity.y
1     3       3        6       5          2      NA         NA
2     4       3        7       7          3      NA         NA
3    11       2        9       3          3       1          1
4    22       1        5       5          2      NA         NA
6    22       3        3       4          3       2          2
```